# How to record performance flame graph without minimized names?

Tags: performance, google-chrome-devtools, flamegraph

We're trying to record performance data on a production environment, but given that everything is minified the flame graph generated uses the minified names.

Is there a way for the flame graph to use the unminified names? I've been trying with a sourcemap, but it doesn't seem to work.

Ideas?

Comment: Sourcemap works though, I can view the individual components in the Chrome's source panel. The flamegraph is still minified.

Comment: File a report on https://crbug.com

Comment: I doubt it's just Chrome, because the same happens in Firefox.

So it's either not possible, or I'm doing something wrong...

Comment: It may just mean that both browsers have the same bug.